# Vista Shellview Help button

Tags: button, windows-7, windows-vista, windows-shell

I have created a namespace extension with VC 2005... I was wondering how to utilize the Help button located on the vista toolbar to display the help document for my product. Currently the help button is available but clicking it does not do anything.

I was wondering how to handle the help button in Vista and 7 as this is a new feature that was not available in previous windows versions like XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing Help button on the explorer's toolbar sends a message to your ShellView's window procedure in the form of WM_COMMAND with control or menu item id = 0x7091.